# How to make a cell address non changeable on coping & pasting?

Tags: excel

I am including my cell address (ie c3) to in different places in my excel sheet by coping and pasting it.

But it got change when I paste it.

I want to make the cell address non changeable. 

How can I achieve it.

Comment: Use `$C$3` to stop it changing during a copy and paste. Use `INDIRECT("C3")` and it will not change when you insert or delete rows or columns either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for absolute addressing.

Just place a dolor sign ($) before row and column number.

Your c3 will be $c$3 as absolute address.

This absolute address will never change in copy/pasting.